# UITableView deleting row is crashing in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am trying to delete row from `UITableView` in iOS.

In `UITableView` , i show files list that located in document directory.

I want to delete file from document directory.

Here is the code for delete.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        self.fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        [self.fileManager removeItemAtPath:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.txt",cell.textLabel.text]] error:NULL];


        [tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

The error message is

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

However when i try to delete , it crashing.

Please help me.

Comment: yes i updated my question. please recheck.

Comment: Provide an `NSError*` parameter at `error:`, if there's any error and the file is not removed you'll get a clear inconsistency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You method `numberOfRowsInSection` is not getting updated properly. You need to make sure that the value it returns changes whenever you add or delete item(s).

It's often best to feed all the data you're working with into an `NSMutableArray` and then in `numberOfRowsInSection`, you would use something like `return [arrayOfData count];`.

Comment: yes i used return [self.array count]; in my numberOfRowsInSection.

Comment: Yes, but you don't appear to be deleting an items from that array in the code you posted.

Comment: So how to delete that item from Array? Thanks you for answering bro.

Comment: I can't quite tell which item you should delete from the code above, but use `NSMutableArray` instead of `NSArray` and you'll get functions like `removeObjectAtIndex:`. You can't easily remove items from `NSArray`. (More on NSMutableArray [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html))

Comment: Yes i change to NSMutableArray and tried with these code [self.array removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  and still error.

Comment: Hmm, can you update the question with the code you currently have for both functions?

Answer (score 1):

It should reflect back to the method which returns row count.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
//return array count
}
```

delete element from array.
Steps:
1 : search element index from array
2 : user removeObjectAtIndex method to remove it.